# macOS Catalina cannot remove file from trash

Tags: macos, root, trash

I have already tried everything which comes to my mind I cannot remove file from trash `OPTION` key doesn't work same as `sudo rm -rf` - says `Operation not permitted` same using root user.

Comment: What are the full permissions on the file you are trying to delete?

Comment: me - R&W, staff Ronly , everyone Ronly

Comment: That's not full permissions. What is the output of `ls -lo filename`?

Comment: `ls: c: Operation not permitted`

Comment: Where is the file?  What version of macOS?  It could be in a SIP restricted location or if you are on Mojave+ you haven't given Terminal.app [full disk access](http://osxdaily.com/2018/10/09/fix-operation-not-permitted-terminal-error-macos/).

Comment: Ok i gave terminal full disk access. Permissions `drwxr-xr-x@` and after `rm -rf` gives  `rm: c//SafariFamily: Operation not permitted
rm: c/: Directory not empty`

Comment: Try disabling SIP and delete as described in this *Apple Developer Forums* thread [Can't Remove SafariFamily](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/109513)

Comment: OK after disabling SIP in recovery mode `csrutil disable` I was able to remove file from trash. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After disabling SIP in recovery mode `csrutil disable` You will be able to remove file from trash. After remember to activate `csrutil` in recovery mode.