# macOS 10.15.3: Cannot delete peculiar file

Tags: macos, mac, terminal.app

I have just moved on to a new MacBook Pro(15 inch, 2017), and I am trying to delete a very peculiar file:

```
/Users/tommy/Desktop/com.apple 07-11-49-482.SafariTechnologyPreview/SafariFamily
```

`rm` doesn't work:

```
tommy@MACBP-5 Desktop % sudo rm -r -f -v "com.apple 07-11-49-482.SafariTechnologyPreview/SafariFamily"
Password:
rm: com.apple 07-11-49-482.SafariTechnologyPreview/SafariFamily: Operation not permitted
```

and I can't see the permissions of the file:

```
tommy@MACBP-5 com.apple 07-11-49-482.SafariTechnologyPreview % sudo ls -a -l
Password:
ls: SafariFamily: Operation not permitted
total 0
drwxr-xr-x@  3 tommy  staff    96 Feb  2 09:00 .
drwx------@ 63 tommy  staff  2016 Feb  2 09:00 ..
```

`chmod` is also not permitted.

Please help me to delete this file.

EDIT1: OK, Here you go, Spiff.

```
tommy@MACBP-5 com.apple 07-11-49-482.SafariTechnologyPreview % ls -ldeO@ SafariFamily
ls: SafariFamily: Operation not permitted
```

EDIT2: That didn't work either, Spiff.

```
tommy@MACBP-5 com.apple 07-11-49-482.SafariTechnologyPreview % sudo ls -ldeO@ SafariFamily
Password:
ls: SafariFamily: Operation not permitted
```

EDIT3: ANSWER FOUND!
I have tried the methods from [macOS Catalina cannot remove file from trash](https://superuser.com/questions/1513237/macos-catalina-cannot-remove-file-from-trash?rq=1/), involving disabling SIP in Recovery Mode via the command `csrutil disable`, which worked.

```
tommy@MACBP-5 com.apple 07-11-49-482.SafariTechnologyPreview % csrutil status
System Integrity Protection status: disabled.
tommy@MACBP-5 com.apple 07-11-49-482.SafariTechnologyPreview % rm -frv SafariFamily
SafariFamily/SafariTechnologyPreview/Preferences.plist
SafariFamily/SafariTechnologyPreview
SafariFamily
```

Comment: Can you edit your Question to give the output of `ls -ldeO@ SafariFamily`?

Comment: Oops, that didn't work. Can you do it again with sudo? `sudo ls -ldeO@ SafariFamily`